# How can I prevent unauthorized connections to my python socket server?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have a simple server written in python that opens and listens on a TCP socket:

```
import socket

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) server_socket.bind(("", 4242)) server_socket.listen(5)

print("TCPServer Waiting for client on port 4242")

while 1:
    client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
    print("I got a connection from ", address)
    while 1:
        data = client_socket.recv(512)
        if data:
            print(data)
        if not data:
            print("Closed Connection")
            break
```

and it works great!

I am now left wondering... any rouge client can connect to my server if they know my IP and port.  Given that my IP and port aren't crazy secure... how can I make sure that the only device that can connect to this TCP socket is my own device?

Can I make some sort of key?  Is that what SSL is about, I am having trouble understanding that.  It seems like SSL just protects the data from being intercepted, but anyone can still connect and write to my listener?

Thanks!

Comment: There are lots of authorization mechanism with different complexity and security they offer. What you use depends fully on what complexity you can afford and what security you need. Insofar the question is too broad. But I recommend to have a look how other protocols (HTTP, POP, SMTP,...) solve this issue, i.e use of plain text passwords, digest auth, TLS with client certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need SSL here. TSL and SSL are protocols that provide an encrypted communication over a network, so even if someone is 'listening'  to that communication, they can't understand it.

The accept() method returns a tuple (conn, *address*) (https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html)

You could choose to drop that connection (don't recive any data) if *address* doesn't match your IP address.

```
if address == your_ip
    # receive data
```

If you don't want to do it programmatically, under Linux, you could use some packet filtering tool like iptables.

```
$ iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 4242 -s <range_of_blocked_ip_addresses> -j DROP
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is the connecting device changes IP addresses with each connection (3G mobile connection).  Is there another way?  I was thinking to drop each connection that doesn't immediately send a "password" message... but that seems kinda crude

Comment: What application are you using on your 3G device? How do you connect and send data? I guess you could take it to to the next level and implement a challenge-response authentication of your own, at application level (using the data you receive on your socket). In this scenario, you would have to encrypt the data using some private key, or someone listening to your traffic could capture the handshake and impersonate your device.